# Rust incremental build not working in vscode devcontainer

Tags: rust, vscode-devcontainer

**Intro:**

I know nothing about rust, I just try to start learning it. Every time I start learning new language - I'm creating isolated environment inside docker container. VSCode + devcontainers does fit my needs.

However I can not make it work w/o issues for rust language...

**Configuration:**

Dockerfile:

```
ARG VARIANT="buster"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/rust:0-${VARIANT}
```

devcontainer.json:

```json
{
    "name": "Rust",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "args": {
            "VARIANT": "buster"
        }
    },
    "runArgs": ["--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE", "--security-opt", "seccomp=unconfined"],
    "settings": {
        "lldb.executable": "/usr/bin/lldb",
        "files.watcherExclude": {
            "**/target/**": true
        },
        "rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command": "clippy"
    },
    "extensions": ["vadimcn.vscode-lldb", "mutantdino.resourcemonitor", "rust-lang.rust-analyzer", "tamasfe.even-better-toml", "serayuzgur.crates"],
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

**Steps:**

1. project init - `cargo init --lib`; inside `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let result = 2 + 2;
        assert_eq!(result, 4);
    }
}
```

2. build and run test; in terminal - `cargo test`. works OK
3. modify source code in `src/lib.rs`:

```rust
let result = 1 + 3;
```

4. try to build and test again

```
vscode ➜ /workspaces/rust (master ✗) $ cargo test
   Compiling rust v0.1.0 (/workspaces/rust)
warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-5d327a17108921ba.13ffvsr0glsfe42f.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-gxppmkfewicn/s-gaal4g2el0-hq3lv3-working/13ffvsr0glsfe42f.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-gxppmkfewicn/s-gaal4g2el0-hq3lv3-working/13ffvsr0glsfe42f.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: failed to build archive: No such file or directory

warning: `rust` (lib) generated 2 warnings
error: could not compile `rust` due to previous error; 2 warnings emitted
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.10m7tz863ds16j5r.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/10m7tz863ds16j5r.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.2g1dgkuj4iwo1dpd.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/2g1dgkuj4iwo1dpd.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.2mlne7zmh6r0bbaz.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/2mlne7zmh6r0bbaz.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.34ce50mpm70vg2xp.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/34ce50mpm70vg2xp.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.3jboau2gf9iotth5.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/3jboau2gf9iotth5.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4kludynsasaig1p8.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/4kludynsasaig1p8.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4mgjk9xqfrl59h15.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/4mgjk9xqfrl59h15.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4x66u4glhx5zajo6.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/4x66u4glhx5zajo6.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.53xipwa889tr5l36.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/53xipwa889tr5l36.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.kijxc3ir8m0c4lu.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/kijxc3ir8m0c4lu.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: error copying object file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.uh788nff365zzlt.rcgu.o` to incremental directory as `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/uh788nff365zzlt.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/4mgjk9xqfrl59h15.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/53xipwa889tr5l36.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/2mlne7zmh6r0bbaz.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/kijxc3ir8m0c4lu.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/10m7tz863ds16j5r.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/uh788nff365zzlt.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/4kludynsasaig1p8.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/3jboau2gf9iotth5.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/4x66u4glhx5zajo6.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/34ce50mpm70vg2xp.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

warning: file-system error deleting outdated file `/workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4g2efw-12rgpao-working/2g1dgkuj4iwo1dpd.o`: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.10m7tz863ds16j5r.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.2g1dgkuj4iwo1dpd.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.2mlne7zmh6r0bbaz.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.34ce50mpm70vg2xp.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.3jboau2gf9iotth5.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.3w9uardnsemqbo8z.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4kludynsasaig1p8.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4mgjk9xqfrl59h15.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4p7ra8ebuf15pp70.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4royndzdbhzs52e2.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4x66u4glhx5zajo6.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.53xipwa889tr5l36.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.kijxc3ir8m0c4lu.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.uh788nff365zzlt.rcgu.o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.19ahr4r5v6berd9h.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libtest-b6a068090bf40c71.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgetopts-1c1e08c768cd8903.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunicode_width-3f4474e7a3a1f53f.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_std-ec55ab174918e77a.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-8d61b92a0a02f53a.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-fc45202bb435016b.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-f2400674c7513725.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-605c3a7d1a5d300d.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-3d4fb4efa907e4e8.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-65207f030ab23308.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-76ca199cb0186109.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-1e3e01ed4f561dc1.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-dd8dddcba7c13fee.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-00b13d31c3420656.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-e4c8460b81557bd5.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-600d46e5f0005455.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-e4a08a2585b62d37.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-fbc21ec567cb9dc7.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-10b3fa8e49bd978f.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-64625b73694ffce7.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-fb6b78ac543a58ee.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-1d1f2d1bec6f51b8.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-acf5ff6e9595d982.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.10m7tz863ds16j5r.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.2g1dgkuj4iwo1dpd.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.2mlne7zmh6r0bbaz.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.34ce50mpm70vg2xp.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.3jboau2gf9iotth5.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4kludynsasaig1p8.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4mgjk9xqfrl59h15.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.4x66u4glhx5zajo6.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.53xipwa889tr5l36.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.kijxc3ir8m0c4lu.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

5. and again

```
   Compiling rust v0.1.0 (/workspaces/rust)
error: unable to copy /workspaces/rust/target/debug/incremental/rust-u7gm7mcexrpp/s-gaal4kvted-13shv61-working/3w9uardnsemqbo8z.o to /workspaces/rust/target/debug/deps/rust-edc6e6500c367432.3w9uardnsemqbo8z.rcgu.o: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: could not compile `rust` due to previous error
```

i.e. after any minor code editing test not compiled/launched

If I execute `cargo clean && cargo test` - it does work, but I think this is ineffective to rebuild everything all the time.

**Question:**
Can someone explain me how to get rid of these errors and make it work w/o `cargo clean` after each minor change I made?

Comment: If you execute `cargo clean` **once**, does it work?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman no, it does not. I need to run `cargo clean` every time if I modified code. otherwise I got error and warnings about missing files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got correct answer [on Github Issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/issues/1487#issuecomment-1143907307)

Problem was because of enabled **VirtioFS** on macOS 12.2

- works w/o extra configuration if **VirtioFS** disabled in docker settings on **macOS 12.2** (but very slow)
- also works with **VirtioFS** enabled on **macOS 12.4**

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found some working options. Problem was around target folder, so I just made some manipulations around it.

1. use `target` folder outside the workspace and run test with `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` env variable

```
sudo mkdir ../target
sudo chown vscode:vscode ../target
CARGO_TARGET_DIR=../target cargo test
```

2. same idea but with `config.toml`. Add `.cargo/config.toml` inside project folder or root folder.

```
[build]
target-dir = "/tmp/target"
```

3. peeped the solution in this [blog post](https://purton.tech/blog/faster-rust-incremental-builds/). Mount target folder as volume. Just added some config to `devcontainer.json`

```
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspace,type=bind,consistency=delegated",
    "mounts": ["source=rust-target-volume,target=/workspace/target,type=volume"],
    "postCreateCommand": "sudo chown vscode:vscode /workspace/target",
```

but `cargo clean` will produce an error output (not a big problem, just annoying)

```
error: could not remove build directory

Caused by:
  failed to remove directory `/workspace/target`

Caused by:
  Device or resource busy (os error 16)
```

So I finished with `post-create.sh` script

```bash
#! /bin/bash/

# grant permissions to mounted rust volume
chown vscode:vscode /rust-volume

# create /.cargo/config.toml in root folder
mkdir /.cargo/
touch /.cargo/config.toml
cat << EOF > /.cargo/config.toml
[build]
target-dir = "/rust-volume/target"
EOF
```

and updated `devcontainer.json`

```
    "mounts": ["source=rust-volume,target=/rust-volume,type=volume"],
    "postCreateCommand": "sudo sh ./.devcontainer/post-create.sh",
```

However, I only found a working option, but I don't understand why it doesn't work without some extra tweaking. If someone can explain this in technical language, you are welcome. Just in case - I used macOS as host machine.